# I can't show image imported from database inside SVG

Tags: angular, svg, sanitization

I am trying to import a picture from my database into an image in an SVG, I used to work with `<img>` and I had no problem showing the picture but when I tried to show it inside an SVG I got this error :

```
Cannot GET /SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20http://localhost/doc/image.jpg%20(see%20https://g.co/ng/security
```

and this is my code, the AVG is so big, so I just putted the image part:

**HTML**

```
  <svg class="animated" " version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <image [attr.xlink:href]="url" height="139.85" width="111.45" x="122.19" y="87.55"/>
  </svg>
```

**ts**

```
 let objectURL = this.dataService.Url + '/doc/' + Candidat.photo;

 this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(objectURL);
```

I can't seem to find any solution and to know what is causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in this

```
 this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(objectURL);
```

I just removed it and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing [attr.xlink:href] with [src]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I got `Can't bind to 'src' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:image'.`